# How to make Github Pages markdown content look like the one on Github

Tags: github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

Apparently, Github Pages uses a different markdown processor than the one used by Github. I am having trouble trying to render mathematical expressions like `$O(N^2)$` on GitHub pages which work fine on Github

In my project, I only have a bunch of markdown files organized into folders without any Jekyll config files or custom Github workflows set up. I tried just creating  a `_config.yml` file in project root with one line as `markdown: GFM` but that didn't work

Also, decorated highlights like the one below works on Github but not on Github Pages

```
> [!NOTE]
> Some insightful text
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're taking of setting the Markdown processor in `_config.yml` requires you to use Jekyll. ([See docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/setting-a-markdown-processor-for-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll))

To add similar functionality, you will need to manually add support in your Markdown files.

For mathematical expressions, you can do so by using a tool like [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).

In your Markdown file:

```markdown
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>

Centred formulae: 

\\[ x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a} \\]


Inline formulae:

\\( x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a} \\)
```

To add support for styling of blockquotes, simply add the desired CSS rules to your Markdown files.

```markdown
<style>
    blockquote {
        /* style rules */
    }
</style>
```